# web service manager - is that an implementation of service locator pattern

Tags: java, web-services, design-patterns

I am using Spring+maven+hibernate configuration for writing Rest ful web services. Now, these web services are used by mobile applications and through web applications. 
I have a requirement to create something like a web service manager ie.., In the controller , instead of having many methods mapping to different services, I should have only one url and based on the parameter to that url , I should be able to route the request to different services.

1. I read about Service Locator pattern.Should I use this pattern for my requirement? Can I use service locator with Spring? 
   From what I read, service locator seems to offer a way to identify the services but that is what my controller is doing in spring. Am I right in my understanding ?
2. Service locator uses some cache to access the services faster . In that case, should it not be implemented on the client(Web application side) instead of the server side ?
3. Please help me understand the service locator pattern. Should I know JNDI in order to understand this pattern?

Comment: We'd need to know a lot more details. That said, look at Spring Cloud; it has a whole lot of these components ready out of the box (you may be looking for Eureka and Zuul).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring and the Service Locator Pattern are essentially opposites.

Spring is a Dependency Injection container. You specify the dependencies in the Spring Bean through injection points (field, constructor, setter), and when Spring creates the Spring Bean, the Spring DI container will resolve the dependencies and inject the values into the Spring Bean through the injection points.

In the Service Locator Pattern, the class uses a static reference to a "service locator" and asks the service locator to provide the dependencies. The Service Locator Pattern hides JNDI and the InitialContext from the class. This is opposite to the way Spring works.